# Powershell Get-ADGroupMember export to CSV -- throwing error "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]'..."

Tags: powershell

Third day noob with Powershell here.

**Problem:** We have several AD groups which follow a prefix naming convention. For example, "IT_1", "IT_2", "IT_3" and so on. I am attempting to export a csv with member details from each "IT_" group, along with the name of the group.

The output should have the following columns populated with data. The column GroupName will refer to IT_1, IT_2, i.e the name of the group.

```
"name","GroupName","distinguishedName","objectClass","objectGUID","SamAccountName","SID"
```

My code can work for a single group. "IT_1". For example:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "IT_1"'

Get-ADGroupMember $groups `
| Select-Object name, @{Name='GroupName';Expression={$groups.Name}}, distinguishedName, objectClass, objectGUID, SamAccountName, SID `
| Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\dude\Desktop\users.csv"
```

However, when I alter the groups variable with a wildcard "IT_*" as per below:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "IT_*"'

Get-ADGroupMember $groups `
| Select-Object name, @{Name='GroupName';Expression={$groups.Name}}, distinguishedName, objectClass, objectGUID, SamAccountName, SID `
| Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\dude\Desktop\users.csv"
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required 
by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:3 char:19
+ Get-ADGroupMember $groups `
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

What am I missing here?

I am sure this is a simple fix for an experienced user.

Answer (score 1):

The [-Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2019-ps#parameters) parameter of Get-ADGroupMember does not allow an array, so you need to loop over the results from Get-ADGroup

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "IT_*"' | ForEach-Object {
    $groupName = $_.Name
    $_ | Get-ADGroupMember | 
         Select-Object name, @{Name='GroupName';Expression={$groupName}}, 
                       distinguishedName, objectClass, objectGUID, SamAccountName, SID

} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\dude\Desktop\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Inside the ForEach-Object loop, the `$_` automatic variable represents the ADGroup object for each iteration</sup>